# C# - Read numbers from a textfile and output averages

Tags: c#

I've looked at previous posts and none have the answer that I'm looking for.
I'm new to C# and trying to get this little application to work.
I have a file named "hours.txt" with 30 numbers in it and I want to read the file and output the Average and the Highest Number, but I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried changing the array to a string but I'm just really stuck on how to get this to work. Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
        int[] hoursArray = new int[30];
        StreamReader fileSR = new StreamReader("hours.txt");
        int counter = 0;                                             
        string line = "";            
        line = fileSR.ReadLine();            
        while (line != null)
        {
            hoursArray[counter] = line;
            counter = counter + 1;
            line = fileSR.ReadLine();
        }
        fileSR.Close();    

        int total = 0;
        double average = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < hoursArray.Length; index++)
        {
            total = total + hoursArray[index];
        }
        average = (double)total / hoursArray.Length;

        int high = hoursArray[0];
        for (int index = 1; index < hoursArray.Length; index++)
        {
            if (hoursArray[index] > high)
            {
                high = hoursArray[index];
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Highest number is: " + high);
        Console.WriteLine("The average is: " + average);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I would also suggest posting how the file appears. I'm assuming it's one number per line, would that be correct? And are the numbers integer values?

Comment: When you step through this in a debugger, specifically where/how does it fail?

Comment: look at Tommy's answer. This is likely the only issue as the rest of the code looks sound from glancing at it.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong since your are putting a string into a int place.

```
hoursArray[counter] = line;
```

Parse string to int first.

```
hoursArray[counter] = int.Parse(line);
```

Comment: This is correct, as it can be seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) the return type for ReadLine is a `String`

Comment: @stuartd yes, and due to the fact that ReadLine returns a string, it must be parsed to an Int. Your comment makes zero sense.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative method, using LINQ, the code could be replaced with the more concise:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("hours.txt");
int[] values = lines.Select((l) => int.Parse(l)).ToArray();
double average = values.Average();
int peak = values.Max();
```